# Does Apache 2 gzip json output by default?

Tags: php, apache, gzip

I'm using this PHP code for json output. Does apache gzip it by default? Or, how can I check to make sure?

```
header('Content-type: application/json');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0,no-cache,no-store,post-check=0,pre-check=0');
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
echo json_encode($response);
```

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for. http://www.simonwhatley.co.uk/how-to-configure-apache-to-gzip-your-components

Answer (score 35):

This is what did the trick for me:

(assuming you have access to apache configuration)

```
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/json
```

I added this line directly in `/etc/apache2/mods-available/deflate.conf` (so it will work for every json file on the webserver) maybe someplace else is better suited in your use case (e.g. if you only want to enable json compression for a single web application and not by default).

edit: In google chromes developer tools you can easily check if your content is served compressed or uncompressed: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/a/4613

Comment: Might also need `AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/json`

Answer (score 2):

No gzip is normally not used you have to enforce that yourself.

In the simplest case you just need to add this php line:

```
ob_start("ob_gzhandler");
```

See also the official [php documentation](http://php.net/function.ob-gzhandler.php).