# Encode/decode JSON keys?

Tags: java, json, parsing, jackson, gson

I want to send a minified version of my JSON by minifying the **keys**.

The **Input JSON string** obtained after marshalling my POJO to JSON:

```
   {
       "stateTag" : 1,
       "contentSize" : 10,
       "content" : {
          "type" : "string",
          "value" : "Sid"
       }
   }
```

**Desired JSON STRING** which I want to send over the network to minimize payload:

```
{
   "st" : 1,
   "cs" : 10,
   "ct" : {
      "ty" : "string",
      "val" : "Sid"
   }
 }
```

Is there any standard way in java to achieve this ??

PS: My json string can be nested with other objects which too I will have to minify.

**EDIT**:

I cannot change my POJOs to provide annotations. I have XSD files from which I generate my java classes. So changing anything there is not an option.

Comment: I think the bandwidth this would save is minimal and you would offload the storage from the network by having a mapping between the long-key and the short-key client/server side.

Comment: On the client side user will have to interpret your 'desired json'? Why not use apache deflate option  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19254859/does-apache-2-gzip-json-output-by-default

Comment: Here is an example http://thegeekyland.blogspot.com/2015/11/serializing-and-deserializing-json-from.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this in Jackson by using `@JsonProperty` annotation.

```
public class Pojo {

    @JsonProperty(value = "st")
    private long stateTag;
    @JsonProperty(value = "cs")
    private long contentSize;
    @JsonProperty(value = "ct")
    private Content content;

    //getters setters
}

public class Content {

    @JsonProperty(value = "ty")
    private String type;
    @JsonProperty(value = "val")
    private String value;

}

public class App {

    public static void main(String... args) throws JsonProcessingException, IOException {

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

        Pojo myPojo = new Pojo(1, 10, new Content("string", "sid"));

        System.out.print(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myPojo));

    }
```

Outputs:

```
{
  "st" : 1,
  "cs" : 10,
  "ct" : {
    "ty" : "string",
    "val" : "sid"
  }
}
```

SOLUTION 2 (Using Custom Serializer):

This solution is specific to your pojo, it means for every pojo you will need a new serializer.

```
public class PojoSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Pojo> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Pojo pojo, JsonGenerator jgen, SerializerProvider provider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        /* your pojo */
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeNumberField("st", pojo.getStateTag());
        jgen.writeNumberField("cs", pojo.getContentSize());

        /* inner object */
        jgen.writeStartObject();
        jgen.writeStringField("ty", pojo.getContent().getType());
        jgen.writeStringField("val", pojo.getContent().getValue());
        jgen.writeEndObject();

        jgen.writeEndObject();
    }

    @Override
    public Class<Pojo> handledType() {
        return Pojo.class;
    }

}



ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();

Pojo myPojo = new Pojo(1, 10, new Content("string", "sid"));

SimpleModule sm = new SimpleModule();
sm.addSerializer(new PojoSerializer());
System.out.print(om.registerModule(sm).writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myPojo));
```

SOLUTION 3 (Using a naming strategy):
This solution is a general solution.

```
public class CustomNamingStrategy extends PropertyNamingStrategyBase {

    @Override
    public String translate(String propertyName) {

        // find a naming strategy here

        return propertyName;
    }

}

ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
Pojo myPojo = new Pojo(1, 10, new Content("string", "sid"));

om.setPropertyNamingStrategy(new CustomNamingStrategy());

  System.out.print(om.writerWithDefaultPrettyPrinter().writeValueAsString(myPojo));
```

Comment: I cannot change my POJOs. I get XSD files from which I generate my java classes. So changing anything is not an option

Comment: Can you use your java classes as a parameter to methods ? If so i will suggest another solution using custom serializer.

Comment: I recieve the data sent as an `Object` type. Ex: **Client**: `HttpEntity entity = new ByteArrayEntity(jsonContent.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    ( (HttpPost) httpUriRequest).setEntity(entity);` On **server**: `@POST
 @Consumes({"application/json"})
 @Produces({"application/json"})
 public String handlePostRequest(Object resource) {`

Comment: So you won't know whether a particular property will exist or not in your pojo?

Comment: I have a variable `resourcetype`  sent along from which I decide which resource is coming and use switch cases to handle different resources. Actually there are many resources to be created so I take a general object, else I will have to write separate function for each resource type

Comment: @Ghukon: Though you can provide the custom serializer you mentioned, maybe it would be of some help

Comment: I have provided both custom serializer and custom naming strategy solutions. For naming strategy solution you can look  com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.PropertyNamingStrategy class source code. A camel case solution is defined in there.

Comment: So for naming strategy, a sibgle strategy is to be defined for all conversions from longnames to shortnames?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96778/discussion-between-ghokun-and-siddharth-trikha).

Answer (score 2):

Use the annotations... 
with gson:
adding `@SerializedName("st")` over the Class Member will serialize the variable stateTag as `"st" : 1`, it doesnt matter how deep in the json you are going to nest the objects.

Comment: I cannot change my POJOs. I get XSD files from which I generate my java classes. So changing anything is not an option